# Vagrant in Docker Container not working (trying to lint Vagrantfiles)

Tags: docker, vagrant, gitlab-ci, static-code-analysis

I just don't get it right ... I'm trying to create a docker-container with vagrant installed to lint my Vagrantfiles in a Gitlab CI pipeline. But all I get ist this result:

```
$ cd src/main/kube-cluster && vagrant validate
==> vagrant: A new version of Vagrant is available: 2.2.16 (installed version: 2.2.6)!
==> vagrant: To upgrade visit: https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html
No usable default provider could be found for your system.
Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
"providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.
The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, which
is available for free on all major platforms.
If you believe you already have a provider available, make sure it
is properly installed and configured. You can see more details about
why a particular provider isn't working by forcing usage with
`vagrant up --provider=PROVIDER`, which should give you a more specific
error message for that particular provider.
```

For full pipeline, see https://gitlab.com/sommerfeld.sebastian/v-kube-cluster/-/pipelines/304344599

My Dockerfile is rather simple

```
FROM ubuntu:focal
LABEL maintainer="sommerfeld.sebastian@gmail.com"

# Avoid beeing stuck at tzdata
ENV TZ="Europe/Berlin"
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends virtualbox=6.1.6-dfsg-1 virtualbox-qt=6.1.6-dfsg-1 virtualbox-dkms=6.1.6-dfsg-1 \
    && vboxmanage --version \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates=20210119~20.04.1 \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl=7.68.0-1ubuntu2.5 \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libcurl4=7.68.0-1ubuntu2.5 \
    && curl -O https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.6/vagrant_2.2.6_x86_64.deb \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ./vagrant_2.2.6_x86_64.deb \
    && vagrant --version \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

But anyway I try, I always get the abouve result from my pipeline. Anyone got an idea on how I can fix my Image?

Alternatively I'm also open to another way to lint my Vagrantfiles.

Comment: It becomes tricky to execute Vagrant provider-less in a container like this, even though the provider does not matter in this case. kubectl manifest validation has a similiar issue. The best alternative here would be ruby/rubocop linting, which provides some measure of validation, and would be significantly easier inside a container.

Comment: I guess I found a solution ... apparently you can use vagrant validate with --ignore-provider flag. Then you don't need a provider. Hence I removed virtualbox from my image. Downside is provider-specific settigs are skipped. But still, this way it seems quite simple and should suffice. See https://gitlab.com/sommerfeld.sebastian/v-kube-cluster/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml